# Kendo ui grid command template click link to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

How do I make the click event of the template? It is not going to function.

```
command: [{
   name: "openMoveModal",
   template: "<a class='k-grid-decreaseIndent k-button'><span class='fa fa-arrows'></span></a>",
   click: openMoveModal
}
```

Function

```
function openMoveModal(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign onclick event into your template.

```
template: "<a class='k-grid-decreaseIndent k-button' onclick='openMoveModal($(this))' ><span class='fa fa-arrows'></span></a>"
```

Here [small dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/olafE)

Comment: Opps Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: openMoveModal is not defined! (openMoveModal) function in other javascript file.

Comment: Is file with function loaded? If you check loaded scripts in your browser, do you see that file with function? Because this problem is caused because it doesn't found function. But how you can see in example, syntax is working.

Comment: I've been using in the angularjs control function.

Comment: Solved! { name: "openMoveModal", click: openMoveModal, template: "<a class='k-grid-openMoveModal k-button'><span class='fa fa-arrows'></span></a>" }

Comment: Thanks Rıza.. Your solution works like a charm. I thınk you should answer your own questıon so that I can upvote it:)